# How do I find specific values in a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Suppose my table is TEST_123 Which has the following records:

```
id |  cid | result
------------------
1  |  C-1 |   TAM
2  |  C-1 |   TAM
3  |  C-2 |   RAM
4  |  C-2 |   TAM
5  |  C-3 |   SAM
6  |  C-3 |   SAM
```

Now I want such cid's which has only one type of result, so the answer should be C-1 AND C-3 but not C-2 since it has two different type of results. Need Oracle query for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 3):

You simple need to understand `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

The answer is as simple as

```
select cid
from TEST_123
group by cid
having count(distinct result) = 1
```

Note **group by** selects the distinct keys from `CID`; the **having** filters on condition valid for all the records *in the group*, in your case `count(distinct result) = 1`

Comment: Thanks Marmite.. Though it pretty answers my query, I was stuck at                                               
 select cid
from TEST_123
group by cid
having count(result) = 1, didn't put distinct...                    But one doubt, with this query when am putting where clause for result = TAM, it gives me C1 and C2,  but what i actually desire is only C1, can you understand me?

Comment: If you filter (with `WHERE`) only `TAM` - then all remaining groups has only one key (`TAM`) per definition, so `C2`in the result is OK. If you are looking for a *keys with only one type of result, which is `TAM`* you must formulate `HAVING count(distinct result) = 1 AND max(result) = 'TAM'` (you can use `MIN`as well because there is only one value of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use exists, its a little bit tricky cause every group result should be same

```
 select t1.* from TEST_123 t1 where exists(
             select 1 from TEST_123 t2 where t2.cid=t1.cid
                                      and t2.result=t1.result
                                      group by t2.cid,t2.result
                                      having count(*)=
                                       (select count(*) from TEST_123 t3
                                       where t3.cid=t2.cid)
                                      )
```

Exmple

```
with TEST_123 as
(
select 1 as id , 'c-1' as cid , 'tam' as result from dual
union all
select 2 as id , 'c-1' as cid , 'tam' as result from dual
union all
select 3 as id , 'c-2' as cid , 'tam' as result from dual
union all
select 4 as id , 'c-2' as cid , 'ram' as result from dual

)

select distinct t1.cid from TEST_123 t1 where exists(
                 select 1 from TEST_123 t2 where t2.cid=t1.cid
                                          and t2.result=t1.result
                                          group by t2.cid,t2.result
                                          having count(*)=
                                           (select count(*) from TEST_123 t3
                                           where t3.cid=t2.cid)
                                          )
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00e1ad127e8942e44649fc37f5ff647d)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @zaynul's answer, here is another variation:

```
with TEST_123 as
(
select 1 as id , 'c-1' as cid , 'tam' as result from dual
union all
select 2 as id , 'c-1' as cid , 'tam' as result from dual
union all
select 3 as id , 'c-2' as cid , 'tam' as result from dual
union all
select 4 as id , 'c-2' as cid , 'ram' as result from dual
)
select * from test_123 where cid in (
    select cid from test_123 group by cid having count(distinct result) = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.cid from 
(select cid, count(*) as count from table_1 group by cid, result) t 
group by t.cid 
having count(*)=1;
```

Should work for you

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.cid = t.cid AND t1.result <> t.result);
```